# How to write a single click event in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have created a form that allow users to close a form by clicking anywhere on the enlarged picture form (There are 3 objects to consider) and go back to the other form, which is called: "frmPhone". There's an actual picture on the form: "frmPhonePics" which is what I'm using to accomplish what I'm trying to do (was unable to insert an image on here. Sorry.) What I want to do is write a single click event to close the large picture form to allow the user to close it absolutely anywhere in the form, but I don't know how to do that. Here's the code I have so far:

```
Private Sub frmPhonePics_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Click
    frmPhone.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map the click handler for various object to one thing, if that is what you are asking:

```
Private Sub frmPhonePics_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
       ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
          Handles MyBase.Click, Handles  picLarge.Click, Handles otherThing.Click

   frmPhone.Show()         
   Me.Hide()           ' should be Me.Close?
End Sub
```

Not sure why it is `MyBase.Click` in your code instead of `Me.Click`.  Is this a subclassed form?

Comment: You don't need the extra Handles statements.  Only one is needed:  e.g. "Handles MyBase.Click, picLarge.Click, otherThing.Click"

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you have a picture on your `frmPhonePics` form. If you double click that (from the VBA editor), you should be taken to the code - for example, you might see

```
Private Sub Image1_Click()

End Sub
```

Now all you have to do is add your code there:

```
Private Sub Image1_Click()
  Me.Hide
  frmPhone.Show()
End Sub
```

Note - the order matters, since `frmPhone.Show()` will "hijack" the code flow until it's dismissed, and in your code `Me.Hide` will not execute (so the form will not close) until `frmPhone` has been dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly suggest using a DoubleClick instead of a single Click.  The chances of an errant click doing the wrong thing is very great.

The easiest way is right from the designer.  Write the sub routine, then for each control, in the properties window, click the events icon(thunderbolt) and assign the sub routine to the double-click event.

Alternatively, dispense with the `Handles` clause completely and use a series of `Addhandler` statements in the Load event handler.  If you put a unique string in the names of the controls or if it's all the controls, you can iterate through the controls and use one addhandler statement for all of them

```
For Each c As Control In Me.Controls
    AddHandler c.DoubleClick, AddressOf Ctrl_DoubleClick
Next

Private Sub Ctrl_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'Do stuff
End Sub
```